# Automate bash answer when wait is made with python click library

Tags: python, bash

I need to test something that asks me for two params. The code that asks me for those params is implemented using click.prompt.

I've seen in other posts and tested that if it's two simple bash reads then the following works:

```
echo -e "param1\nparam2" | bash test.sh
```

Being test.sh something like:

```
read param1
read param2
echo param1 param2
```

In this case I have something like:

```
import click
param1 = click.prompt('Insert param1')
param2 = click.prompt('Insert param2', hide_input=True)
print(param1 + " " + param2)
```

Doing the same thing as before it only fills param1 and still requests for param2.

I'm guessing that click.prompt executes something different from a read, but I couldn't find if there is another way for waiting for user input

Thanks

Comment: Your Python code is not the equivalent of your `bash` code; the issue is your use of `hide_input`. If you drop that, it will work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over that parameter. I have to automate something that is equivalent to the python code. I'll look if I can add that to the bash test and check if I can solve it

Comment: I just added -s to the second param and echo -e still works fine